# How to query object associations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am building a Rails 5.2 app.
In this app I got three main objects, Conversation, User and Assignment.

**Conversation**

Has_many :assignments

```
- Id
- Entity_type
- Entity_subtype
```

**User**

Has_many :assignments

```
- Id
- Name
```

**Assignment**

*This is a polymorphic association.*

```
- Id
- User_id
- Assignable_id
- Assignable_type

<Assignment id: "5475728b-a0c0-4959-a8a7-17af9a5e224b", account_id: "243c9502-c3ab-4362-907b-ca630c2caf04", user_id: "cdd3c6be-ac78-46f2-a7ae-7f2299b6fedb", assignable_type: "Conversation", assignable_id: "f753e48c-6a67-4410-9748-8454e5904405", role: "owner">
```

I want to create a query where I find (check) if two individual Users are connected to the same Conversation through an Assignment.

**I tried this and it returns conversations but how can I check both user IDs?:**

```
Conversation.joins(:assignments).where(:assignments => {:user_id => "cdd3c6be-ac78-46f2-a7ae-7f2299b6fedb"})
```

But how can I check the to User IDs are connected to the same Conversation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
Conversation.joins(:assignments)
.where(:assignments => {:user_id => ["cdd3c6be-ac78-46f2-a7ae-7f2299b6fedb", "c974419c-1bbd-4537-9d4f-d8df262ace82"]})
.group("assignable_id", "conversations.id")
.having("count(1) > ?", 1)
```

What it should do is to first fetch all the assignments for given `user_ids`, then group it by `assignable_id` and filter those that have more than one assignments.

*Note: As `user_id` I added just some random UUID - I suppose you want to search for the specific Users in your code.*

Comment: Thank you! I get this error through: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "conversations.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function)
LINE 1: SELECT  "conversations".* FROM "conversations" INNER JOIN "a...

Comment: Yes, you are right, forgot about that. I edited the code with missing grouping by "conversations.id".